# Put a custom message on MDB backout queue

Tags: queue, ejb-3.0, message-queue, websphere-6.1

I am using MDBs deployed on WAS 61. I have a queue (X) and a backout queue (Y). When the MDB listening on X fails to process the message, and EJB exception is thrown, the transaction rolls back and I put the original message on the backout queue.
backout queue (Y) has  its own MDB which picks up the message and sends to support team in email. So far so good.

Now support team would be helped a lot if in addition to the message in the email, they can also see the exception that was thrown by the EJB. Because looking at just the message ,it is not possible to figure out what went wrong. Is there way to add the exception to the original message before putting it in backout queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectMessage
 :

> An ObjectMessage object is used to send a message that contains a
>   serializable object in the Java programming language ("Java object").
>   It inherits from the Message interface and adds a body containing a
>   single reference to an object. Only Serializable Java objects can be
>   used.

You can create a class implementing `Serializable` interface & can have proper attributes to hold the exception details. Then by setting this object in `ObjectMssage` you can put it in queue.

```
objectMessage.setObject(object);  //-- Setting serializable object
```

At receiver end, this object can be obtained from the message & exception details can be retrieved form it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Can I do this inside my main MDB (X)?

Comment: @Kaushik Yes, you have to change only the message type that you are sending after encountering exception.